# What the marginal distribution looks like in an example

Tags: probability

Consider the random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint distribution given by

[image]

We know that the for the random vector $X=(X_{1}, \dots,  X_{n})$, for $j \in \{1, \dots, n \}$

$$P(X_{j}=x)=\sum_{x_{1}}\sum_{x_{2}} \cdots \sum_{x_{n}}P(X_{1}=x_{1}, \dots, X_{n}=x_{n})$$

For the example we have that the marginal of $X$ and $Y$ is

[image]

[image]

But I want to know what the sums look like, e.g.

$$P(X=0)=\sum_{\text{what here?}} P(\text{what here?})$$

I don't see how obvious it is to go from definition to example, any help for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the random variable $X$ takes values in the set $\mathcal{X}$, and the random variable takes values in the set $\mathcal{Y}$, then, in the case $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are both countable,
$$
      \mathbb{P}(X = x) = \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = y) \ \forall x \in \mathcal{X}
$$
If we arrange the joint probabilities of $X$ and $Y$ into a matrix, say $P$, such that
$$
       P_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(X = i, Y = j) \ \forall i \in \mathcal{X}, j \in \mathcal{Y}
$$
then, $\mathbb{P}(X = x)$ is the sum of all the entries at the row $X = x$ in the matrix $P$.

In the example in your question, $\mathcal{X} = \{0,1,2,3\}, \mathcal{Y} = \{0, 1,2,3\}$, and
$$
     \mathbb{P}(X = 0) = \sum_{y = 0}^3 \mathbb{P}(X = 0, Y = y)
$$
that is, the sum of all the entries of the row $X = 0$.